# Different body for a same resource in REST design

Tags: json, api, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

We have version 1.0 and 2.0 API. In 1.0 , we have a resource `/invoices`. In 2.0, the body is changed for that particular resource. Since that, I want to support 1.0 functinality, I want to keep `'/invoices`'

In swagger 2.0, I couldn't define 2 body parameters for a same REST resource.
What is the best naming convention in this case for `/invoices` resource

eg:

- `https://example.org/accounts/1.0/invoices  (version 1.0)`
- `https://example.org/accounts/2.0/invoices  (version 2.0)`  ---> will support 1.0 invoices functionality. Also, how can I name the new resource for invoices with new body ?

Comment: i would have 2 separate open api docs

Comment: @DanielA.White, problem is only one swagger can be hosted in our gateway..